# react css update style onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I would like to clip the image every click with animation. so every click the image should be bigger until it reach 100% size and it's work well, but the problem is the animation is only work at the first load. here is my js code:

> ```
> import React, { Component } from "react";
> import "./styles.css";
> import styled from "styled-components";
>
> class Loading extends Component {
>   constructor(props) {
>     super(props);
>     this.state = {
>       progress: 10,
>     };
>   }
>   render() {
>     const { progress } = this.state;
>     const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
>       .image-load {
>         clip-path: circle(${progress}% at 50% 50%);
>         animation: circle 2s;
>       }
>
>       @keyframes circle {
>         0% {
>           clip-path: circle(${progress - 10} at 50% 50%);
>         }
>         100% {
>           clip-path: circle(${progress} at 50% 50%);
>         }
>       }
>     `;
>     return (
>       <StyledWrapper>
>         <div
>           className="container"
>           onClick={() => this.setState({ progress: progress + 10 })}
>         >
>           <img className="image-load" src={require("../../assets/mkpro.png")} />
>         </div>
>       </StyledWrapper>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> export default Loading;
> ```

and this is my css file:

> ```
> .container {
>   position: relative;
> }
> .image-load {
>   width: 600px;
>   height: auto;
>   clip-path: circle(10% at 50% 50%);
>   animation: circle 2s;
> }
> ```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to put `%` in keyframe after `${progress - 10}` :

```
const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
    .image-load {
        clip-path: circle(${progress}% at 50% 50%);
        animation: circle 2s;
    }

    @keyframes circle {
        0% {
            clip-path: circle(${progress - 10}% at 50% 50%); // <--- HERE
        }
        100% {
            clip-path: circle(${progress}% at 50% 50%); // <--- HERE
        }
    }
`;
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-animation-progress]

Comment: ohh, didn't notice that. tyvm btw. im trying for hours :))

Comment: It took an hour for me also :)